# botframework attachments with white space

Tags: botframework

I seem to have problem downloading attachments that has URL with white space.
this is how ContentURL is posted in message.Atatchment object:

> http://localhost:9000/content/8a684db8?file=Microsoft Edge.pdf

before attempting to download the file in stream using WebClient I replace spaces with %20, try UrlEncode etc, with no luck.

If I attach same file without spaces i.e.

> http://localhost:9000/content/8a684db8?file=MicrosoftEdge.pdf

all works.

Comment: More detail needed.   Downloading where?  Which API?

Comment: using emulator and bot builder 1.2.1 (C#) bot connector 1.1.0. downloading using Webclient.OpenRead into Stream

Comment: forgot to mention that what i am getting is "Internal server error 500" after substantial wait on OpenRead with url that has spaces